# Sales amount group by Payment Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Below is the output of the sales data done using Cash & Card. There is a new requirement to save Cash&Card transaction where in CashAmount and CardAmount will be saved to identity the different amounts as shown below.

```
    Sales   Payment_type    CashAmount  CardAmount
    9.00    Card                0.00    0.00
    10.00   Cash                0.00    0.00
    8.80    Cash_Card           5.00    3.80
    9.35    Cash_Card           5.00    4.35
```

Now in the monthly Sales Statement We show the Cash, Card,Cheque transactions amount. Cash&Card transaction Cash amount should also be added to Cash column now and Card sales Amount should be added to the card column. Final output

```
     Sales  Payment_type    
     17.15          Card                
     20.00          Cash
```

```sql
select 
    sum(a.total_amount) as Sales,
    b.Payment_type          
from
    sl_sales_trans_master a
    inner join sl_payment_master b on a.payment_type_id = b.payment_type_id            
where
    a.reading_master_id=@ReadingMasterID
group
    by b.Payment_type
```

Can you please guide me how to approach this.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with your query? Why `CardAmount` is equal 18.35 for sum of 10.0 +9.0 ?

Comment: Sorry updated the Card Sales Amount 9+3.8+4.35 = 17.15

Comment: Where is the column total_amount in your sample data?

Comment: Why the `CashAmount` and `CardAmount` for first 2 lines are `0.00` ?

Comment: @Squirrel - because it is exclusively only  Cash or exclusively only CARD payments. But for the last 2 lines customer paid using both Cash and card. Hence cashamount and cardamount are saved.

Comment: You need to "convert" `CardAmount` and `CashAmount` into `Sales` for `PaymentType` = `Cash_Card` ;) Use `CASE WHEN...`

Answer (score 3):

You could write a query whose output is of the following style:

```
| Sum of Card Payments | Sum of Cash Payments |
-----------------------------------------------
|                17.15 |                20.00 |
```

That query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN t.Payment_Type = 'Cash_Card' THEN t.CardAmount
            WHEN t.Payment_Type = 'Card' THEN t.Sales
            ELSE 0.0
        END
    ) AS "Sum of Card Payments",
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN t.Payment_Type = 'Cash_Card' THEN t.CashAmount
            WHEN t.Payment_Type = 'Cash' THEN t.Sales 
            ELSE 0.0
        END
    ) AS "Sum of Cash Payments"
FROM
    sl_sales_trans_master t
```

Comment: @PrathapGangireddy you're welcome... Consider accepting one of the answers that were helpful to you, please.

Comment: @PrathapGangireddy sorry, you haven't. At least, you haven't clicked the symbol for accepting on any answer here.

Comment: ok m not sure..for me its showing as clicked..and the answer is accepted

Comment: @PrathapGangireddy Ok, weird... I cannot see any of the answers being accepted. Maybe a bug or a delay.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation.  You haven't posted precise details of your table structures, but hopefully the approach is reasonably clear for you to adapt as needed. Essentially it's treating the Cash_Card combination as if it were two separate rows.

```
with cte as (
select payment_type, sales as amount from sl_sales_trans_master where payment_type in ('Cash', 'Card')
union all
select 'Cash', cashamount from sl_sales_trans_master where payment_type = 'Cash_Card'
union all
select 'Card', cardamount from sl_sales_trans_master where payment_type = 'Cash_Card'
)
select sum(amount) as amount, payment_type from cte group by payment_type
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to pull the data for each payment type either from the `sales` column or the appropriate column.  You can do this using a lateral join with some conditional aggregation:

```
select v.payment_type, sum(v.sales) as sales
from sl_sales_trans_master stm cross apply
     (values ('Cash', (case when stm.payment_type = 'Cash' then stm.sales else stm.cashamount end),
             ('Card', (case when stm.payment_type = 'Card' then stm.sales else stm.cardamount end)
     ) v(payment_type, sales)
group by v.payment_type;
```

Alternatively, you could put the values in separate columns:

```
select sum(case when stm.payment_type = 'Cash' then stm.sales else stm.cashamount end) as cash,
       sum(case when stm.payment_type = 'Credit' then stm.sales else stm.creditamount end) as credit 
from sl_sales_trans_master stm
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h8oEHwaVL1pE2o5j8w3XCf/0). While not as efficient or terse as @deHaar's answer, I found this one easy to verify.

```
select type, sum(amount)
from (
select
sum(sales) as amount, 'total_card_only' as detail, 'card' as type
from sl_sales_trans_master 
where Payment_type = 'Card'
union 
select sum(cardAmount), 'total_card_mixed', 'card' as type
from sl_sales_trans_master 
where Payment_type = 'Cash_Card'
union
select
sum(sales), 'total_cash_only', 'cash' as type
from sl_sales_trans_master
where Payment_type = 'Cash'
union 
select sum(cashAmount), 'total_cash_mixed', 'cash' as type
from sl_sales_trans_master 
where Payment_type = 'Cash_Card') as temp
group by type
```